# Cannot change the default python version used by the node-gyp?

Tags: python, node.js, node-gyp

When i run the the command the `node-gyp rebuild` command I get the following error:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@9.6.1 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/home/rando/.cache/node-gyp/9.6.1'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-45-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/rando/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin/node" "/home/rando/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--python=/home/rando/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/bin"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/rando/Desktop/git/master-node/node/browser_engines/src/browsers/webkit
gyp ERR! node -v v9.6.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have tried to change the node-gyp default python version like below:

- Command :  `node-gyp rebuild --python=/home/rando/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/bin`
- Command :  `node-gyp rebuild --python=2.7`
- Command : `node-gyp rebuild --python=2.7.18`

And all comand resulted with the same Error. They are using python3 instead of python passed to configuration.

Environments Details

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Python Version: 2.7.18
- Node version: V9.6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this issue by exporting the `NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON` like below:

```
export  NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/bin/python
echo $NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON
```

Comment: I had to downgrade node from v18 to v14 along with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the [suggestion from Rando Shtishi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66694929/823533), but it didn't work. I've solved by exporting a `PYTHON` env var with that same value:

```
export PYTHON=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON, i was getting the error that python version is outdated. Required python version is >=3.6 .

With python3, it was giving syntax error as it was trying to execute something written with python2. So what worked for me is

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass
yarn install && yarn start
```

Comment: so it used python2 in the end?

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problems by switching node-gyp from python3 to python2

Options for configuring node-gyp python path are described here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency